# MetadataType bug in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've wracked my brain on using the MetadataType / buddy class to get DisplayName / Display attributes working on my Entity Framework classes in MVC3.  In my views, if I use @Html.LabelFor, I still just get the property name rather than the display attribute.  My use case and set-up is very simplistic:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ProductMetadata))]
public partial class Product
{
}

public class ProductMetadata
{
    [Display(Name = "Why does this not work????")]
    object ProductName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Discontinued Date")]
    object DiscontinuedDate { get; set; }
}
```

If I then use an Html helper like LabelFor:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.First().ProductName)
```

I still just get the property name in my output.  Even if I do this programmatically in a custom Html extension, I just get the property name rather than the extected attribute value:

```
ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData).DisplayName
```

Any ideas or help on this would be appreciated. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Don't say it is MVC3 bug. It has been in the wild for long enough for someone to report bug like this :) Moreover this is a simple usecase, it would never get past the QA.

Comment: I figured it was something I was missing.  But, it was a bug in preview1, which had me curious.  It's funny that no matter how many times I looked at that code, I never even noticed that I didn't have property access levels set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working because the properties are private in the ProductMetadata class. Change it to

```
public class ProductMetadata
{
    [Display(Name = "It works!!!")]
    public object ProductName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Discontinued Date")]
    public object DiscontinuedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DisplayNameAttribute

```
[DisplayName("Propertyname")]
public string PropertyName {get;set;}
```

Comment: I should have clarified a bit more.  I get the same result whether I use the DisplayName attribute or Display attribute.